# Ошибка подгрузки изображений в html

Tags: html

У меня есть html страница. Все изображения у меня в папке "pages and images" когда страница в этой папке, то изображения отображаются, а когда я страницу переложил в папку "Математика", картинки не перестали отображаться.

Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: И снова вы и снова вопросы нeочем...<br>
Если хотите чтобы картинки отображались независимо от местоположения страницы используйте абсолютные пути к ним. Т.е. если у вас было например `<img src="../images/img">` привидите все к виду `<img src="/images/img">`<br>
PS:учите матчасть -.-

Comment: Так как Вы написали я сделал, но изображения не отображаются.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/pages and images/jscookmenu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/pages and images/ThemeRibbon/theme.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pages and images/ThemeRibbon/theme.js"></script>`

Comment: А какое отношение имеют `src` javascript'a и `src` изображений, которые у вас и не отображаются?^^

Comment: У меня меню на странице, когда я страницу поместил в папку математика оно отображается, но не картинками, а текстом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте прописывать пути к картинкам от корня, например:

```
 <img src="/images/someimage.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Пробовал не пашет!

Comment: Вместо того чтобы ждать пока вам подсунут полностью правильный ответ последовали бы моему совету и начали бы учить матчасть...<br>

Comment: Простите, но у меня оно не работает!

Comment: Конечно, не будет работать, потому что хтмл страницу надо копировать вместе с папками images и pages. Либо в src опять же прописывать жесткие пути типа: `file://localhost/C:/images/someimage`, но в этом случае при переносе на другой компьютер опять всё пропадет... )

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы не понимаете сути. src javascript'a подключает файл скрипта. Картинки в меню можно привязать с помощью css. Но если у Вас используется все-таки img, то тут может быть несколько проблем: во-первых, русские символы в url, во-вторых, знак пробела в url. Это все надо кодировать. Например, код пробела %20, если не ошибаюсь. Вывод - по возможности не использовать знак пробела в имени папки и использовать английский язык в имени. А первая Ваша ситуация связана с тем, что браузер при проблемах с адресом "ищет" объект в директории, где лежит страница. Вот и отображались картинки.

Comment: У автора вопроса вообще много проблем, с формулировкой в частности.